# Regex matching "a > b > c" pattern?

Tags: regex

What would be a proper regular expression to match a pattern of ">" or "|" having minimum 3 occurrences like the following example? I would like to match either ">" or "|" (not both) in a given text with irregular spacing in between.

Should Match

- " a>b>c > d >e"
- " a|b|c | d |e"

Shouldn't Match

- " a>b>c" (only 2 ">")
- " a|b>c | d |e" (not either ">" or "|")

**Sample Java Code to Test the Expressions**
(only backslashes are escaped)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> patterns = new ArrayList<String>();
    patterns.add("/((\\s*\\w+\\s*>\\s*){3,}|(\\s*\\w+s*\\|\\s*){3,})\\w/g");
    patterns.add("^( ([\\w\\s]*>){3,} | ([\\w\\s]*\\|){3,} )[\\w\\s]*$");
    patterns.add("/(>|\\|)[^>\\|]*\\1[^>\\|]*\\1/");
    patterns.add("/[\\w ]*([>|])(?:[\\w ]*\\1){2,}[\\w ]*/");

    List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add("a > b > c > d");
    test.add("a >b> c> d");
    test.add("a>b>c>d");
    test.add("a>b>c");

    for (String s : test) {
        for (int i = 0; i < patterns.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(s + "[Pattern " + i + "] " + s.matches(patterns.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the capture the group? and will they need to have characters in between?

Comment: capturing the group is a nice to have. There are no characters in between except spaces i can guarantee that

Comment: This " a>b>c > d >e" has characters in between. You say that there will be only spaces?

Comment: I think i got your question wrong, sample is a realistic sample but there can be a number of unicode characters if this is what you are asking? I mean " aa>bbb>c > dd >eeee"

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I thought. That's what my answer matches. cheers

Comment: just provided a sample test in java, will try all answers now

Comment: Nice job buddy... I like your style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(\s*\w+\s*([>\|])\s*)(\s*\w+\s*\2\s*){2,}\w*/
```

This works assuming you need a character (or more between the | or > symbols) - the symbols cannot be mixed in any way in the line having the regex applied to it. And of course irregular spacing is handled. Full groups are additionally captured.

Cheers.

Comment: I find `^( ([\w\s]*>){3,} | ([\w\s]*\|){3,} )[\w\s]*$` to look a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Willem So do I, but it's not equivalent. I'll try to make mine nicer. cheers

Comment: @d'alar'cop do i need to remve anything while testing in java?

Comment: Yeah - all \ symbols will need to be escaped like this: \ becomes \\     also you won't need the / symbols at the edges.. also if there is a 'g' flag you will put it hanging alone before the literal string of the pattern... yes it's painful

Comment: What you say if i use this

((\\s)*(\\w)*(\\s)*((>)(\\s)*(\\w)*(\\s)*){3,})|((\\s)*(\\w+)*(\\s)*((|)(\\s)*(\\w)*(\\s)*){3,})

Comment: Maybe some unnecessary brackets - but yeah the \\ escapes are all accurate.. is it not working in Java?

Comment: This now works for all test cases;

(there are space characters first, than a word, than cpace characters, and after those; 3 or more the same consept includes a '<' in front of it)
-or-
(the same consept uses '|')

I must now start to think about the construction of the words, am i going to catch one word only, or will there be a sequence of words.

I mean the (\\w)* sign by word.

Comment: And is important if there could be more simple form of this.

Comment: Yes I see.. remember that * means "zero or many". Also since this particular question is answered - you might like to tick the answer maybe? - as for capturing word for word - you might open a new question (or you can split() on '>' or '|' then trim()... that would do it)

Comment: Ah yeah there may be a simpler version... I'll edit my answer

Comment: Sure i will mark the answer, but i must be sure if this is the simplest and correct way to do it. It will take a little bit longer.

Answer (score 1):

```
/[\w ]*([>|])(?:[\w ]*\1){2,}[\w ]*/
```

Match a > or a |, and then make sure it appears twice more (at least).

Answer (score 0):

You can try grouping and back referencing

```
/(>|\|)[^>\|]*\1[^>\|]*\1/
```

Comment: is it a good idea to test these on http://regexpal.com/ it does not seem to match "a > b > c > d" ?

Comment: @OnurGunduru It was using javascript syntax, remove the starting and ending `/` and check

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of tests, i decided to use this regex:

```
((\\s)*(\\w)+((\\s)+(\\w)+)*(\\s)*((>)(\\s)*(\\w)+((\\s)+(\\w)+)*(\\s)*){3,})|((\\s)*(\\w)+((\\s)+(\\w)+)*(\\s)*((|)(\\s)*(\\w)+((\\s)+(\\w)+)*(\\s)*){3,})
```

to match all those test cases:

```
    test.add(" a > bbb >   ccc >   dc");//true
    test.add("a > b > c > d");//true
    test.add("a >b> c> d");//true
    test.add("a>b>c>d");//true
    test.add("a>b>c");//false
    test.add("a>b>c| d >e >f");//false
    test.add(">a>b>c> d >e >f");//false
    test.add("<a>b>c> d >e >f");//false
    test.add("a>b>c< d >e >f");//false
    test.add("a>b>c> d >e >f>");//false
    test.add("a b>b>c d > d >e >f> a bcd");//true,
    test.add("ayse ciog > ayse ciog > ayse ciog > ayse ciog");//true
```

And getting successfull results now, thanx for your help.

Comment: Hey buddy. Since that appears to be a form of the regex I provided - do you reckon you can tick or maybe at least thumb up the answer? (as is the etiquette on SO)

Comment: I am clicking to mark the right answer but it says : "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". What must i do?

Comment: You should accept mine buddy... or at least thumb it up - it's actually not usual for someone to answer their own question unless no suitable answers have been posted. The answer you put _is_ the Java version of my answer - which was generic regex (which is what the question asked for)

Comment: This is just the way that Stackoverflow works... i.e. it's not a blog, it's not a place of sharing ideas (so to speak) it's a Question & Answer system

Comment: Thanks brother. I know you meant no ill - all the best!